MariaDB on Mac via Homebrew: MySQL impossible after computer restart
I have installed MariaDB locally on my Mac using Homebrew. Everything works fine until I restart my computer. After a computer restart I cannot access my local database server anymore. The files in /opt/homebrew/var/mysql/are still there, but something seems to be broken and I have no idea what. The only solution I could find is to completely re-install MariaDB and set up all databases again which is obviously highly annoying.
Does anyone have any clues on the reason for this break? I did think about stopping MariaDB before shutting down the computer, but I forget that everytime. Also, it hasn’t always been this way. It’s a fairly recent behaviour.
[EDIT 1]
Here’s the error message when connecting to MySQL after a computer restart:
mysql -u root -p             
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock'

[EDIT 2]
I now tested to stop MariaDB before shutting down the computer – and the problem even occurred immediately after restarting MariaDB, before shutting down the computer. nabim sademba’s comments (thank you!) actually led me to the following output after rebooting the computer – even brew services start mariadb apparently does not start it:
% brew services list    
Name    Status  User  File
httpd   started myusername ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.httpd.plist
mariadb none    root  
php     started myusername ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.php.plist
php@7.4 none          
php@8.0 none          
php@8.1 none          
php@8.2 none          

% brew services start mariadb
==> Successfully started `mariadb` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mariadb)

% brew services list         
Name    Status  User  File
httpd   started myusername ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.httpd.plist
mariadb stopped root  ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mariadb.plist
php     started myusername ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.php.plist
php@7.4 none          
php@8.0 none          
php@8.1 none          
php@8.2 none          
% 

And here’s /opt/homebrew/etc/my.cnf (after the failed restart of MariaDB)
#
# This group is read both by the client and the server
# use it for options that affect everything
#
[client-server]

#
# include *.cnf from the config directory
#
!includedir /opt/homebrew/etc/my.cnf.d

[EDIT 3]
And here’s some log data from /opt/homebrew/var/mysql/mycomputer.local.err with error messages about InnoDB (read in a different post to check that)
240815 19:48:34 mysqld_safe Starting mariadbd daemon with databases from /opt/homebrew/var/mysql
2024-08-15 19:48:34 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 11.4.2-MariaDB source revision 3fca5ed772fb75e3e57c507edef2985f8eba5b12 as process 62946
2024-08-15 19:48:34 0 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /opt/homebrew/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2024-08-15 19:48:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.12
2024-08-15 19:48:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of transaction pools: 1
2024-08-15 19:48:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2024-08-15 19:48:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128.000MiB, chunk size = 2.000MiB
2024-08-15 19:48:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2024-08-15 19:48:34 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Missing FILE_CHECKPOINT(234874341) at 234874341
2024-08-15 19:48:34 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Log scan aborted at LSN 234874341
2024-08-15 19:48:34 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2024-08-15 19:48:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2024-08-15 19:48:34 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2024-08-15 19:48:34 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2024-08-15 19:48:34 0 [Note] Plugin 'wsrep-provider' is disabled.
2024-08-15 19:48:34 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2024-08-15 19:48:34 0 [ERROR] Aborting
240815 19:48:34 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /opt/homebrew/var/mysql/digs-bb-mac9.local.pid ended


have you checked if the maria db  service is running ??

yes, it was the first thing I checked, also re-started MariaDB

can you paste the output of :
brew services list
and content of my.cnf file at /opt/homebrew/etc/my.cnf

Thank you, @nabim-sademba. You were right: MariaDB shows as “stopped” – even after brew services start mariadb. I have pasted the output of that and the content of my.cnf in the post.

ok i will  let me write you a few steps in answer  which you can follow if any issue let me know in comment

facing the same problem after upgrading mariadb. INNODB is the cause as in the log: [ERROR] InnoDB: Missing FILE_CHECKPOINT(xxxx) at xxxx
[ERROR] InnoDB: Log scan aborted at LSN xxxx
[ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
Brute force help is https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/318218 if you have backups. Can't be the final solution, I keep exploring.

I have exactly the same problem after every restart. InnoDB: Missing FILE_CHECKPOINT(xxxx) at xxxx

The current version of MariaDB delivered by homebrew has a bug which corrupts the database on shutdown. It seems there is already a new version available, but not in homebrew yet.

It seems that a new homebrew version 11.5.2 has been released which solves the problem.

First, you can find out if you have an "InnoDB problem".
Use Terminal:
brew services

You should see this:
mariadb stopped  ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mariadb.plist

To be sure locate /opt/homebrew/var/mysql/the_name_of_your_computer.err (I have homebrew installed in /opt so you eventually have to find the proper path, sorry I don't know it. You can use Shift + Command + . to see hidden files.) Find this error:
InnoDB: Missing FILE_CHECKPOINT(xxxxxxxxx) at xxxxxxxx

Solution
Add to /usr/local/etc/my.cnf.d/my.cnf
[mariadb]
innodb_force_recovery = 6

If homebrew is installed in /opt then use /opt/homebrew/etc/my.cnf (if the file doesn't exist, create it).
Now restart MariaDB in Terminal:
brew services restart mariadb

Check if MariaDB is running:
brew services

You probable see this:
mariadb started  ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mariadb.plist

Now you can use phpadmin to check and export the tables. I analyzed all tables and the only corrupted (actually not corrupted because it's not a table but a view) one was mysql/mysql.user:
Error 'mysql.user' is not of type 'BASE TABLE'

Unfortunately there is also this error:
Could not save recent table!
#1036 - Table 'pma__recent' is read only

So I could't repair the table/view (maybe someone can help with this) but at least I could export my databases. After exporting I decided to reinstall mariadb. :( I completely removed mysql folder (/opt/homebrew/var/mysql). I also removed innodb_force_recovery = 6 from my.cnf.

UPDATE: It seems that a new homebrew version 11.5.2 has been released which solves the problem. Try 'brew upgrade'. Please let me know if the upgrade itself helped resolve the corrupted database, as I upgraded after the process described below. Also check this thread: MariaDB@10.11.8 Bottle Service - Unsafe Host Shutdown Corrupts InnoDB? #5389

UPDATE 2:
DB corrupted again. From error log:
[Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /opt/homebrew/var/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
[Note] Recovering after a crash using tc.log
[ERROR] Bad magic header in tc log
[ERROR] Crash recovery failed. Either correct the problem (if it's, for example, out of memory error) and restart, or delete tc log and start server with --tc-heuristic-recover={commit|rollback}

I stopped mariadb: brew services stop mariadb
I removed tc.log and added --tc-heuristic-recover=rollback to /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mariadb/11.5.2/homebrew.mxcl.mariadb.plist
More about adding arguments in homebrew.
I started mariadb: brew services start mariadb
DB still not working...
I checked error log:
[Note] Heuristic crash recovery mode
[Note] Please restart without --tc-heuristic-recover
[ERROR] Can't init tc log
[ERROR] Aborting

I removed --tc-heuristic-recover=rollback
I restarted mariadb: brew services restart mariadb
DB working...

Thanks a lot! I also had to reinstall MariaDB. For now it seems to work, even though in between I had the following problem after a MariaDB restart: ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'. However, after my last DB-restart this did not happen again. I’ll keep an eye on that and post again when I can be more certain.

Cant believe this:
[mariadb]
innodb_force_recovery = 6
worked, thanks!!!


ensure proper permission

sudo chown -R $(whoami) /opt/homebrew/var/mysql
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /opt/homebrew/etc/my.cnf.d
sudo chown $(whoami) /opt/homebrew/etc/my.cnf



update the configuration

nano /opt/homebrew/etc/my.cnf

# update the following line in [mysqld] section:

[mysqld]
socket=/opt/homebrew/var/mysql/mysql.sock
datadir=/opt/homebrew/var/mysql

# save the file and exit


restrat mariadb service with homebrew

brew service restart mariadb

# check the status

brew services list


enable auto start on system start

sudo cp /opt/homebrew/opt/mariadb/*.plist /Library/LaunchDaemons/
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.mariadb.plist


verify and test


restart
check if mariadb is running

mysql -u root -p


start maria db manually - last resort

mysqld_safe --datadir=/opt/homebrew/var/mysql &



Thanks a lot! MariaDB still shows as mariadb stopped root  ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mariadb.plist after step 3. Might this have to do with the root user? And when trying to start mysql now (step 5), this error message appears: mysql: unknown variable 'datadir=/opt/homebrew/var/mysql'

i corrected it was suppose to be in mysqld not in  clinet-server please correct that and test

no difference unfortunately

I added some log data to the post which I found in /opt/homebrew/var/mysql/mycomputer.local.err which seems to point to InnoDB as possible root of the problem!?
